# Which Exchange 2013 Role will allow mail relay

Tags: exchange, sendmail, smtp, exchange-2013

We have a service that connects to our default receive connector in exchange, which relays the message to external users.
Currently I have configured the service to use my DA account which assigned all Exchange Roles.
I want to create a service account instead of using my DA credentials but i'm stuck as to which admin roles I should select.

To reiterate, the only function that we need is for the service account to be able to authorise mail being relayed externally.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Permission Group**:

```
ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Recipient
```

**Via PowerShell**: *(includes anti-spam bypass)*

```
Get-ReceiveConnector <RelayName> | Add-ADPermission –User “NAME” –ExtendedRights ms-Exch-SMTP- Accept-Any-Recipient,ms-exch-bypass-anti-spam
```

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for this - i've not tried yet as I want to clarify what i have been doing. In Exchange Admin Centre, under Permissions > admin role I can add the service account to predefines admin role groups. When I add the service account to Organization Management (all roles) the service account functions as intended (however i don't want to allow all roles, i'd rather it be the needed roles)

Comment: It doesn't need any RBAC roles at all, that's silly. It simply needs to be given the required permission on the receive connector, as Samuel told you.

Comment: The receive connector's security is set like http://imgur.com/F0pEjSh

Comment: I get the following error:

Comment: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList"
value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ADRawEntryIdParameter".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADPermission], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-ADPermission
    + PSComputerName        : canexchcasvr01.can****c.com

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a dedicated "Frontend Transport" receive connector for this, assign correct permissions as outlined [here](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-2013-configure-smtp-relay-connector/).